# Custom clipping plane with SceneKit

Tags: opengl, scenekit

Is it possible to create a custom clipping plane while using SceneKit? Since you can provide your own shaders, the only thing I need to do is somehow enable GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0. Is this possible or do I have to stick to lower level libraries?

Edit:

I tried to enable the GL state GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0 with a renderer delegate without effect. Here is the relevant code section:

```
class GameViewController: NSViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var gameView: GameView!

 override func awakeFromNib() {
   let attrs: [Int] = [
     NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
     NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 24,
     NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile,
     NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
     0
   ]

   let pixelFormat: NSOpenGLPixelFormat = NSOpenGLPixelFormat(attributes: UnsafePointer<NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute>(attrs))

   gameView.pixelFormat = pixelFormat

   let scene = SCNScene()      
   let obj = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
   obj.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry: "gl_CLipDistance[0] = 0.0;"]
   let objNode = SCNNode(geometry: obj)
   scene.rootNode.addChildNode(objNode)

   // ... create camera and lights ...

   // set renderer delegate
   self.gameView.delegate = self

   // set the scene to the view
   self.gameView!.scene = scene      
   self.gameView!.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()
 }

 func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
  glEnable(GLenum(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0))
 }
}
```

No matter what I try, I get the following error:

```
SceneKit: error,   2: uniform mat4 u_normalTransform;
SceneKit: error,   3: uniform mat4 u_projectionTransform;
SceneKit: error,   4: uniform mat4 u_modelViewTransform;
SceneKit: error,   5: // In model space, must stay in it
SceneKit: error,   6: struct SCNShaderGeometry
SceneKit: error,   7: {
SceneKit: error,   8:   vec4 position;
SceneKit: error,   9:   vec3 normal;
SceneKit: error,  10:   vec4 tangent;
SceneKit: error,  11:   vec4 color;
SceneKit: error,  12:   vec2 texcoords[8]; // MAX_UV
SceneKit: error,  13: } _geometry;
SceneKit: error,  14: struct SCNShaderSurface
SceneKit: error,  15: {
SceneKit: error,  16:   vec3 view; // in view space
SceneKit: error,  17:   vec3 position; // in view space
SceneKit: error,  18:   vec3 normal; // in view space
SceneKit: error,  19:   vec3 tangent; // in view space
SceneKit: error,  20:   vec3 bitangent; // in view space
SceneKit: error,  21:   float shininess;
SceneKit: error,  22:   float fresnel;
SceneKit: error,  23:   vec3 _normalTS; // UNDOCUMENTED in tangent space
SceneKit: error,  24:   vec4 diffuse;
SceneKit: error,  25: } _surface;
SceneKit: error,  26: // Attributes
SceneKit: error,  27: attribute vec4 a_position;
SceneKit: error,  28: attribute vec3 a_normal;
SceneKit: error,  29: // Varyings
SceneKit: error,  30: varying vec3 v_position;
SceneKit: error,  31: varying vec3 v_normal;
SceneKit: error,  32: void main(void)
SceneKit: error,  33: {
SceneKit: error,  34:   _geometry.position = a_position;
SceneKit: error,  35:   _geometry.normal = a_normal;
SceneKit: error,  36:   gl_CLipDistance[0] = 0.0;
SceneKit: error,  37:   // Transform the geometry elements in view space
SceneKit: error,  38:   _surface.position = (u_modelViewTransform * _geometry.position).xyz;
SceneKit: error,  39:   _surface.normal = normalize(mat3(u_normalTransform) * _geometry.normal);
SceneKit: error,  40:   //if USE_VIEW is 2 we may also need to set _surface.view. todo: make USE_VIEW a mask
SceneKit: error,  41:   v_position = _surface.position;
SceneKit: error,  42:   v_normal = _surface.normal;
SceneKit: error,  43:     
SceneKit: error,  44:   // this means that the geometry are still in model space
SceneKit: error,  45:   gl_Position = u_projectionTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.);
SceneKit: error,  46: }
SceneKit: error,  47: 
SceneKit: error, failed to link program: ERROR: 0:36: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_CLipDistance'
```

Am I doing something wrong or is "gl_ClipDistance" simply not available in the OpenGL version SceneKit is using?

Comment: Your shader error is because you've mis-capitalized `gl_clipDistance`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem. A different capitalization doesn't change the error. Plus, in the [OpenGL docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_ClipDistance.xhtml) it is capitalized like I have.

Comment: @UliHeld: no, it's not. You spelled it with a uppercase **L**.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for noticing. Unfortunately it is still not working.  In the mean time I discovered that there are bunch of compatibility problems with custom clipping. Maybe it is easier to use the frustum for clipping.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable certain GL state before SceneKit renders the scene, use a [scene renderer delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012017). In the `renderer:willRenderScene:atTime:` method you can `glEnable` any state your custom shaders depend on.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately this is not working for me. I expanded my question with code samples.

Answer (score 1):

Of the three ways to integrate custom OpenGL code in SceneKit:

(1) node.renderDelegate  but this only applies to the specified node.
(2) SCNPrograms attached to materials.
(3) your own renderer

The state you enable in (1) or (3) apply to any program in (2), so the choice for one or the other in this case depends more on whether custom clipping should apply to specific nodes (use option 1), or all nodes (use option 3).

For (3), see https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate which has all the delegate methods in SCNSceneRendererDelegate as well as references to SCNNodeRendererDelegate and SCNShadable.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but option (1) uses the SCNNodeRendererDelegate which requires a custom renderer. As far as I can tell, this means that there is no other way than to write a custom renderer either for a specific node or for the whole scene.